# Flutter compile error "The integer literal 9223372036854775807 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript"

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to build my flutter app and its throwing compilation error, based on error it seems to be something with flutter files not my code. Any idea how to fix this?

```
PS C:\Users\FlutterProject\tirthankar> flutter build web
Target dart2js failed: Exception: /C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-3.4.0+1/lib/src/X509Certificate/asn1_decoder.dart:163:25:
Error: The integer literal 9223372036854775807 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript.
    int int64MaxValue = 9223372036854775807;
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.


Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             18.3s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
PS C:\Users\FlutterProject\tirthankar>
```

Below is the code in dart/flutter where it fails.

```
static List<int> loadSubContent({@required Iterator<int> iterator}) {
    var len = getContentLength(iterator: iterator);
    int int64MaxValue = 9223372036854775807;

    if (len >= BigInt.from(int64MaxValue)) {
      return <int>[];
    }

    var byteArray = <int>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < len.toInt(); i++) {
      if (iterator.moveNext()) {
        var n = iterator.current;
        if (n != null) {
          byteArray.add(n);
        }
      } else {
        throw ASN1OutOfBufferError();
      }
    }

    return byteArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe int is bounded between 2^62 and -2^62-1, I know you're at the limit of the int value that can be represented in a 64-bit machine but have you tried using the class `BigInt` since the beginning `BigInt bi = BigInt.parse("9223372036854775807");`

Comment: As its flutter file i am not sure if changing that will break anything else..

Comment: Are you running in an emulator or in an actual phone? Maybe check if the device is actually running in a 64bit

Comment: Phone and Emulator works fine, i am only having issue with Chrome(web) version, after your message I changed value of int int64MaxValue = 9223372036854;(removed-775807) and that did worked for me. But I am not sure if it will impact any other area.

Comment: I think `if(length >= BigInt.parse("9223372036854775807"))` should do what you want because you want to reference a number that's too big to use as int in the first place

Comment: I have the same error. How do I find which line of code this error is coming from?

Comment: the error should tell you which file just like the example above